# Exporting Taxonomies to code

Tags: 6, taxonomy-terms, importing-exporting

I'm looking for a way to export Taxonomy vocabs and their associated terms. So far I've found and tested:

[Taxonomy Export](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_export) -- Exports to code using features but doesn't import.

http://drupal.org/node/755986 -- My brief testing with this patch showed mixed results.

Does anyone have any other module suggestions or code solutions? I could write it all into a `hook_install` and then use `hook_update` to update but it doesn't seem like an elegant solution especially for 500+ terms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Also might want to take a look at [Taxonomy CSV import/export](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_csv) or [Taxonomy import/export via XML](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_xml)

Comment: For the record I'm using taxonomy_csv, it doesn't do everything I want but it saves me from the headache of the other solutions.

Answer (score 3):

You might also want to look at http://drupal.org/project/uuid and http://drupal.org/project/uuid_features, which can be used together to export Nodes, Node Revisions, Users and Taxonomy to a Feature.

I haven't done Taxonomy with UUID personally, but it does work quite well with Nodes.

Answer (score 2):

The [Feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) module allows the creation of Taxonomy terms from various sources (CSV, XML, etc). That may help.

Comment: But it doesn't export right?

Answer (score 0):

I have used http://drupal.org/project/exportables with [a patch](http://drupal.org/node/645596) to support exporting the taxonomy and full terms with one tick in features. Have had good success with this

Comment: Which version of exportables did you use? The full patch fails against latest dev.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the module is named Taxonomy Export, it is a light-weight module for managing exports and **imports** of vocabularies and terms.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this module is called [**Node** Import](http://drupal.org/project/node_import), it also says it handles importing/exporting Taxonomies.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you’ll need to install the UUID Features, Features and UUID modules.

Once all those modules are enabled, go to example.com/admin/config/content/uuid_features (or on your administration menu go to Administration –> Content Authoring –> UUID Features Integration, and under “Exportable Taxonomy term bundles” check the boxes for the relevant taxonomy terms.

Go to your features export page at example.com/admin/structure/features/ (or on your administration menu go to Administration –> Structure –> Features), create/recreate the feature and you’ll see “Taxonomy Terms” listed.