# Could anyone suggest a Drupal database versionning tool?

Tags: 7, database, features, version-control

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I manage collaborative development on a Drupal site?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/147/how-do-i-manage-collaborative-development-on-a-drupal-site)

Is there any Drupal database version like GIT for versionning files ? with drush or any thing else ?

I've already used features module but it doesn't cover all needs in database versionning to get back to one saved version of the project.

The real point is to get drupal usable by many "site builders" and can manage conflict. on some features

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the [Backup and Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) module will help you. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> Back up and restore your Drupal MySQL database, code, and files or migrate a site between environments. Backup and Migrate supports gzip, bzip and zip compression as well as automatic scheduled backups.
>
> With Backup and Migrate you can dump some or all of your database tables to a file download or save to a file on the server or offsite, and to restore from an uploaded or previously saved database dump. You can choose which tables and what data to backup and cache data is excluded by default.

Comment: I've edited the question, does "backup and migrate" covers conflict management ?

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you missing?

[Features](http://drupal.org/project/features) combined with [Strongarm](http://drupal.org/project/strongarm) will do a pretty good job.

Comment: If I dive in to this solution, is there an important amount of job to do to get this work?

Comment: yes. you would have to define in your features which site specific database variables you would like to version and add those to your feature like you would have added any other component.